# Ajax GET request with JSON body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, angularjs, query-string, angular-http

Is there any way to send `GET` request body from `AngularJS` to `Rails`?

I have search endpoint `\search`, which should accept for example:

```
languages: [
    { name: 'english', level: 'intermediate' },
    // ...
]
```

How can I pass nested query params through `GET` method?

Comment: using 1.x, you have to stringify and parse json server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
$http.get('/search', {data: {languages: [{...}]}});
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. It's a way to pass data to an ajax request in angular.